# Apache Storm 0.10.0 : Could not get my custom metrics every timeBucketSizeInSecs

Tags: apache-storm, metric

I register my custom metrics in my bolt, code like this, context.registerMetric("et", _executedTuple, 2), this code just count the number of tuples the bolt emitted, and I register metricconsumer in my topology.

But I just get the executedTuple every ten seconds, I just think the metric should be sent every 2 seconds(timeBucketSizeInSecs).

Perhaps you know how to solve the problem!

Comment: Were you able to get the metric.log file?